# Working with message broker(RabbitMQ /Redis) in django azure web site

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, azure-web-app-service

I want to implement asynchronous task queuing system with Celery .

I have a Django web app On azure web app service ,

one of the first steps is to install RabbitMQ or Redis on the server,

How can i do it in Azure?

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 0):

Azure has REDIS for cache as a service:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cache/

Just a heads up, SSL is enabled by default. If you're using Celery 4.0+, you can use

```
broker_use_ssl={'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_NONE}
```

Reference this post:
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4792